# Get associated record based on condition from second table using relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a user table structure like :

```
id | user_id | name
```

second table is booking table

```
id |  user_id  |  category_id  | booking_amt
```

Now i want to get  all the data from booking table where user_id and category_id gets matched.

I'm trying something like this:

I'm getting all data from users table:

```
 $query = User::where(['active'=>1])->get();
```

> Booking Model:

```
public function getAssociatedDealer()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Booking', 'user_id', 'category_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Booking Model:

```
  public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
    }
```

then for the query:

```
 $query = Booking ::where('user_id',$user_id)->where('category_id',$category_id)->with('user')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to get user detail also so i want to do it with relation

Answer (score 1):

Your's `users` table should only have

```
id | name
```

Now, you can have a foreign key relationship with the `bookings` table. And then create relationship functions in the respective models.

In the `User` model.

```
public function bookings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Booking::class);
}
```

In the `Booking` model.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Now you can query the relation.

```
$query = User::whereHas('bookings' , function($query) use($category_id) {
    $query->where('category_id', $category_id);
})->with('bookings')->where('active', 1);
```

In the same way, you can query users.

```
$query = Booking::whereHas('user' , function($query) use($name) {
    $query->where('name', $name)->where('active', 1);
})->with('user');
```

You can query anything by your choice, just keep the syntax in mind.